# passing multiple selectors to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vb6q7yp2/6/)

Script:

```
function nodisplay(para){
   $(para).toggleClass('nodisplay')
} 


$('button').click(function(){
   var finddiv = $(this).siblings('.title'),
       findsel = $(this).siblings('.age');
    nodisplay(finddiv);
    nodisplay(findsel);
})
```

Is it possible to pass multiple selctions to the nodisplay function instead of doing it one by one?
This one isn't working:

```
nodisplay(findsel,finddiv);
```

Comment: Those aren't "selectors", they're jQuery objects. A selector is a string. Your code is *using* selectors in the process of creating jQuery objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the contents of one jQuery object to another:

```
nodisplay(finddiv.add(findsel));
```

The `.add()` method returns a newly-constructed jQuery object from the union of the two original objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function nodisplay(para){
   var para = $(arguments);
   para.toggleClass('nodisplay');
   // console.log(para);
};


$('button').click(function(){
   var finddiv = $(this).siblings('.title'),
       findsel = $(this).siblings('.age');
    nodisplay(finddiv, findsel);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vb6q7yp2/8/

See

[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)